# Get the selected or checked radio button value in JSP

Tags: html, mysql, jsp

I have written a JSP program to get a list of some values from a MySQL database in the form of 4 radio buttons (meaning 4 values from the database) which is working fine.
I am also storing the selected radio button in a session which is showing `true` when I select a radio button and click on `next`, but I want to get all the selected values on submit button. I have provided an action for the "submit" button in another JSP page, meaning I want to show the values on a new JSP page.

I have three questions coming from the database. That is why I have a `<a href>Next</a>` for next so that I can view the questions one by one.
Every question has 4 options and the values I am getting in a list (`ansList.get(i)`) are in the form of radio buttons and every selected radio buttons value I need to show in a new JSP page.

I tried to use `request.getParameter("easy_answers")` in my new JSP page, but I am getting `null`.

What do I need to do to get the values of the selected radio buttons?

```
<%
Server_Sql server_Sql = new Server_Sql();
String ques_id = request.getParameter("easy_questions_id");
String answer = request.getParameter("answers");
int ques = Integer.parseInt(ques_id);
int next_question = ques + 1;
String answer_selected = request.getParameter("answer_selected");
Boolean ans_selected = Boolean.valueOf(answer_selected);
if (ans_selected == true) {
    session.setAttribute("ques_id", ans_selected);
}
String questions = server_Sql.getQuestions(ques);
System.out.println("Question is " + questions);
List<String> ansList = server_Sql.getAnswers(ques);
server_Sql.close_connection();
%>
</head>
<body>
<h3>
    <%=questions%></h3>
<br>
<h3>
    <%
        for (int i = 0; i < ansList.size(); i++) {
    %>
    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="easy_answers" value="answers"
            checked="checked">
        <%=ansList.get(i)%><br>
        <%
            }
        %>
    </form>
</h3>
<br>
<%
    if (ques == 3) {
%>
<form action="results.jsp" method="get">
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
<%
    } else {
%>
<div align="right">
    <a
        href="http://localhost:8082/StudentsServer/questions.jsp?
        answer_selected=true&easy_questions_id=
        <%=next_question%>">Next</a>
</div>
<%
    }
%>
</body>
```

Anything more you want me to elaborate on, please let me know..

Comment: use javascript or jquery to handle the click function. use this link for examples http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/radio/get-selected.php

Comment: Fixed grammar, added some formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep you answers and submit button in the same form tag. Then it would be passed as a parameter to your next JSP:

```
<form action="results.jsp" method="get">
   <%
     for (int i = 0; i < ansList.size(); i++) {
   %>
   <input type="radio" name="easy_answers" value="answers"
        checked="checked">
   <%=ansList.get(i)%><br>
<%
 }
%>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply sir , first my output was coming as answers and then i changed the value inside the <input type="radio"> to value="<%=ansList.get(i)%>" now the output is coming as the last questions selected option , but i want all the questions selected option to be shown , where did i go wrong sir ?

Comment: I am not following you. Can you update your thread with latest code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give multiple selection option then you should use checkbook instead of radio button, as below

```
<form action="results.jsp" method="get">


<%
     for (int i = 0; i < ansList.size(); i++) {
      %>
     <input type="checkbox" name="easy_answers" value="answers"
        checked="checked">
   <%=ansList.get(i)%><br>
<%
 }
 %>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

you will get selected option in array in servlet as below

```
String [] easy_answers = request.getParameterValues("easy_answers")
```